# Interval of existence of maximal solution of first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am just discussing the solution of the differential $x'=f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$ with initial value $x(0)=x_0$. Since $f(x)$ as a polynomial is continuously differentiable indeed $f$ is Lipschitz-continious and hence, it exists a unique solution $x:I \to \mathbb{R}$ on a compact $I$ (Picard-Lindelöf). Let $x$ be a maximal solution of the given IVT. Then let $x:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0>1$. I know have to show/calculate the following:

1. $a= -\infty$ and $\lim_{t \to -\infty}x(t)=1$.
2. $\lim_{t\to b}x(t)$ and
3. $b<\infty$.

Now, all these are very easily shown by solve the IVT straight forward getting $x(t)=\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{e^{2t}(1-x_{0}^2)+x_{0}^2}}$ for any $x_0>1$. But there must be a more rudimental way to get these results by qualitative considerations. One idea I had was the $\omega-$/$\alpha-$limes-set of the Orbit of the solution. But I can't find the arguments.

Is there anybody having ideas for me, please? I am looking forward for your answers! Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Since this is an autonomous 1st order ODE, a [phase line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)) will get you the answers quickly

Comment: Hello, 

do you mean the graph of $f(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$ with phaseline? Well, actually I tried to do so, but I couldn't think of any hint. 

Can you give a hint that is more precise, please? 

Thanks a lot!